# Concerned about a warning from Gparted that says resizing my drive may cause the OS to not boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

So, I am trying to resize one of my partitions (on my SSD) from 30 gigs to 50. GParted gives me this warning that says that failure to boot may occur if I try to move the `/boot` or C: partitions. I have a separate `/boot/efi` partition (that is what holds `/boot` right?) and a different C: partition (the one that is 184 gigs). Is this a message GParted gives whenever we try to resize (and I can ignore it and go forward with the operation) or is it something that might actually cause boot issues?

[Image with error GParted shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6DyU.png)

OS: Pop! OS 21.10
Dual boot: yes, with Windows 11 on the insider dev ring, GRUB is **not** set up

Error message:

```
Header: Moving a partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot

You have queued an operation to move the start sector of partition /dev/nvme0n1p4. Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows system partition C:.

You can learn more how to repair boot configuration in the GParted FAQ.
https://gparted.org/faq.php
```

Note: error message has been typed out as I was not able to copy and paste

Comment: Its typically best to use Windows tools for Windows and Linux tools for Linux. Or use Windows to resize the NTFS partition.

Comment: Expanding partitions to the left(start) side can lead to problems with booting and should be done with care.  Backups are most important in these cases.  Windows will probably handle it easier, but backup of important data should still be done first.  Partition booting usually depends on the first/starting sector, so if that is moved, then boot has a hard time to find it, since it is now missing/moved/not where it was.

Comment: I see, will try with Windows once and get back to it